# Make a graph of accuracy by epoch with mlpclassifier in scikit-learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, plot, scikit-learn, epoch

I would like to test the accuracy by epoch in scikit-learn. However, so far, i have been unsuccessful.

This is my code part of classifying with mlpclassifier:

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 1000
LOG_FOR_EVERY = 10

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(18, 175, 256), batch_size=528,
                    learning_rate_init=0.0001, beta_1=0.001,
                    beta_2=0.001, max_iter=1, warm_start=True)


for i in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

I have also made a graph with this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArlLX.png) but i need to make it continuous and further increase accuracy.

Why is the accuracy not increasing?

Comment: Please add `steps by epoch` and `epochs` arguments in your `fit` function : https://keras.io/models/sequential/

Comment: Maybe you can use this example:-http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_mlp_training_curves.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neural-networks-plot-mlp-training-curves-py

Answer (score -2):

Please try with :

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel(), epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Comment: No param named `epoch` in scikit MLPClassifier.

Comment: You are referring to the `fit()` method in Keras. The question is about `scikit-learn` and has nothing to do with Keras. Please read the questions carefully before posting answers.